# Furnace Connection Question

Tags: furnace

I recently plan to install a smart thermostat in my house and I found there is a pair of wires(black and white) were connected to the Y and B/C terminal of my furnace.

I tried to track where it goes but I found it goes through the wall.

Can anyone tell me what are these two wires used for?

Wires in the white circle are connected to the thermostat and the wires in the red circle are what I am asking.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just found that they are used for the outdoor condenser.